# Choice specific variables in multinomial logistic regression

Tags: identifiability, multinomial-logit

For a MNL regression, is it possible to include independent variables that are only populated for one of the choices? Let's say there are 3 choices an individual has. However, only choice 3 has an attribute (call it X3) that the other two options do not have. Can we estimate the effect of X3 on choice 3?

My understanding is, we can estimate effect of X3 for but only *among* those who choose 3.

Thank you!